# How do you make peach soda?

Tags: beverages, soda, peaches

I was at a local brewpub and they had made a peach soda. I have 5 gallon kegs to carbonate with, but how do you make peach soda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Torani Peach Syrup!

[image: Picture of Torani Peach Syrup]

It's readily available online or at coffee shop supply outlets. [Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GZGWSI)

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen a recipe, but I suspect it was made the same way most other soda is: peach syrup + carbonated water.

You can buy the syrup from places that sell it for making snow cones, but that might be more expensive than rolling your own (peach flavor + some acid + sugar).

Good luck.

Comment: When you say "some acid", what does that mean? What kind of acid? Any idea on ratios of water, flavor extract, and "acid"? Also do I need to add sugar?

Comment: You need sugar if you make your own from scratch. If you use the syrup, you just need to experiment with the concentration and you shouldn't need anything else. The acid is usually citric, see the Torianai Peach Syrup ingredients.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably one of these mixed with carbonated water:

- Simple syrup and artificial peach flavor
- Concentrated peach juice (probably with added sugar)